# Dynamic VLOOKUP with INDIRECT

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-indirect

I need to perform a VLOOKUP with INDIRECT to a different workbook and to a specific sheet.

The name and the sheetname should be dynamically entered inside the direct function (they can be found in cell H2 and H3). This is where I am having trouble. I am trying the following:

```
=(VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'["&H2&".xls]"&H3&"'!$1:$100000"),4,FALSE))
```

The 'cells' are not being recognised and seem to be part of the string rather than variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a volatile function within VLOOKUP will cause you all sorts of headaches.

I suggest you use an intermediate cell containing `INDIRECT("'["&H2&".xls]"&H3&"'!$1:$100000")`. This at least forces calculation to take place in a certain order.

Comment: Thanks,
I am now storing the indirect in H4 and let the VLOOKUP direct to it.